# How can I have an absolutely positioned element underneath it's sibling with z-index?

Tags: html, css

I've got a layout with a left sidebar to the content. Sidebar is absolutely positioned, width 200px, and content has a margin-left of 200px. That's all dandy, but I just began animating the navigation, I would like it to slide in from underneath the content. See fiddle.

Problem is, the absolutely positioned sidebar is **above** the content, **regardless of setting the z-indexes to 1 and 2, respectively**.

Setting the sidebar's z-index to -1 has it slide in correctly, but places it underneath it's parent, making navigation unclickable.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jduhrump/2/)

```
<div class="parent">
  <aside class="animated fadeInRight">
    ... navigation ...
  </aside>
  <main>
    ... content ...
  </main>
</div>
```

How do I have the sidebar slide in from underneath the content, but above the parent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [All About.... Z-Index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305669/all-about-z-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! I've figured it out.

As per [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)...

> **Note:** z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

So simply adding **position: relative** to the `<main>` fixes it.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jduhrump/3/)

Answer (score 0):

If you add position: relative; to your main box, the z-index css will be applied. The way you currently have it, the z-index is not working because it needs to have a position style added to it.

Comment: Righto, just figured that out. Thanks!