# How can I place a line behind my divs?

Tags: jquery, html, css, line

I want to move place my dashed line **behind** my divs.
It keep staying on the top of my divs.

Here what I currently have right now :

[image]

Here what I am hoping to get :

[image]

```
**CSS** 

/*Background Border*/
.border-center {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.slide:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 3px #3498db dashed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top:-2px;
  right: 10%;
  left: 40%;
  width: 25%; 

}
```

I wish I can put more code, since my rep is low, I got this warning :

[image]

More details : [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/1q6ur85k/)

Comment: You can set the `z-index` on your divs to mirror that.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305669/all-about-z-index

Comment: Always post your code in your question please. You saw the warning when you posted a link to jsFiddle, yet you chose to ignore it and tried to sidestep it by highlighting a link as code. If jsFiddle ever goes away or is inaccessible, then your question loses all value without the code in it.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I'm going to fix that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

giving your fiddle a `z-index of 0` accomplished this, and a `background:white` on your `.tl-box`

http://jsfiddle.net/1q6ur85k/2/

Comment: zoom in, you'll see the text is in front of the lines

Comment: oh I see, ok, you need to give those boxes a `background:white`

Comment: Well answer ! Abdul !

Answer (score 0):

In short, the z-index of the boxes need to be higher than the lines and the boxes need to have a background color of white to keep the line from showing through.

Here it is done very roughly: http://jsbin.com/tupiqiqida/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Thanks for your answer here, but can you please modify my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/1q6ur85k/) instead. I want to see your solution works in there. Then I will make sure to accept your answer.