# Override text due to expanded width in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to use a template of an admin panel, so i've logged into that site:
http://bootstraptaste.com/theme/niceadmin/index.html

I've launched "developer tools" in my Google Chrome, and set the container width css property to **"150%"** instead of **"100%"**.
The container width was expanded as expected, but for some reason, when scrolling to the right all of the container text overrides the side bar!

I've been trying for hours and still can't figure out why this is happening, and what to do so the text won't override the left panel.

Any help ?

Comment: " text overrides the side bar" not sure what this means, can you add you code and a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a high z-index to #sidebar

```
#sidebar {
  width: 180px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: #394a59;
  z-index: 99; <----------------
}
```

[A thread on z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305669/all-about-z-index)

Comment: Shalom Elad, can you explain further?

Comment: Shalom Shalom. Check the link in my post for a detailed explanation on z-index.

Comment: The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

Comment: @elad.chen I know that is another question: but if I also want the "Home/Dashboard" to stand still when I scroll right (So the user can click it immediately even if he scrolls right).. is there an easy way of doing this ?

Comment: @elad.chen can you refer to my last question please?

Comment: Hi, Just to make sure, you want the breadcrumbs section ( The with bar with Home / Dashboard ) to remain visible when scrolling occurs ?