# How can I specify which picture is on top?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a really simple animation on a webpage. When the images overlap, the wrong ones are on top and the one I want on top is on the bottom. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All About.... Z-Index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305669/all-about-z-index)

Comment: Can you elaborate more? like which plugin are you using or some sample code?

Comment: Check z-index but please always add your code so we can exactly know how to help

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to provide more information about your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS `z-index` Property

The `z-index` property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.