# Place the navigation bar at the top of other elements

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-navigation, css-position

I am working on a website and at this problem I got stuck
I have created a navigation bar and applied fixed position property in css,
but below it, I have created an hover element but this hover display above the navigation bar.
Here are some screenshots:)

[Here it is not creating any problem(before scrolling down)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrMmh.png)

[after scrolling down it is displaying on the navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70HP0.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All About.... Z-Index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305669/all-about-z-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works:

```
nav {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 40;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the z-index of the navigation bar large enough to always be larger than the hovering element, even when it's hovering.

Answer (score 0):

Make the z-index of the navigation greater than the z-index of the hover element in css.

```
nav { 
  z-index: 2
}

hoverElement {
  z-index: -1 
}
```